# Serilog unable to loginto elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, serilog

I have created a simple C# program. It configures serilog to use the elastic search sink as below

```
string url = "http://localhost:9200/";
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.LiterateConsole()
            .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(url)))
            .CreateLogger();
logger.Error("This is an error Message");
```

I can see the log in literate console but nothing in elastic search. Do I need to create and specify an Index in the elastic search sink options? What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Unable to log into ES in the sense? Could you get your indexes through `Curl` in ES?

Comment: I could not get to my indexes. When I look at _cat/indices I did not see the index being created. However it is currently working fine. The change that i made is to rename the cluster and the node in the ES config file. I know that that should not do anything with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was because of an authentication issue after installing x-pack.
I temporary disabled it by adding

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

in elasticsearch.yml and kibana.yml. After that it started working.